# Insert out of order exception when connecting to Terracotta

Tags: java, ehcache, terracotta, ehcache-bigmemory

I am facing below exception while connecting to the Terracotta server from the EHCache client.

Versions:

EHCache: `2.10`

Terracotta: `4.3.2`

Terracotta server logs:

```
2017-04-06 05:25:27,269 [WorkerThread(hydrate_message_stage, 4, 4)] ERROR com.tc.net.protocol.tcm.HydrateHandler - Error hydrating message of type REQUEST_MANAGED_OBJECT_MESSAGE (12) java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Inserts out of order
        at com.tc.util.BasicObjectIDSet.doRangeInsert(BasicObjectIDSet.java:62)
        at com.tc.util.BasicObjectIDSet.insertRange(BasicObjectIDSet.java:47)
```

EHCache client logs:

```
com.tc.exception.PlatformRejoinException: lookup failed for ObjectIDObjectID=[1] due to rejoin
        at com.tc.object.ClientObjectManagerImpl.lookupDone(ClientObjectManagerImpl.java:298)
        at com.tc.object.ClientObjectManagerImpl.lookup(ClientObjectManagerImpl.java:533)
```

Comment: what are your ehcache / terracotta server versions ? and configurations ? Are those logs happening anytime your start them, or is there a specific sequence to make that happen ?

Comment: Fixed title of the question because it was not descriptive enough. The old title was moved to the text of the question.